# C - NULL checking when making an API?

Tags: c, null

Let's say you are making a fairly robust heavily tested API for some purpose... like a data structure. Other people are going to download and use your library in their own coding projects and so you want it to be pretty air tight.

In your API, you have many function calls like this:

```
void remove(struct myDataStruct *s, void* element_to_be_removed)
{
    if (element_to_be_removed == NULL)
       // Output an error, not allowed to enter NULL.
    else if (isEmpty(s))
       // Output an error, cannot remove something from empty structure.
    else
    {
       // Everything is safe.
       // Begin removing the element to the data structure.
    }
}
```

What about adding the following:

```
if (s == NULL)
   // Output an error, data structure initialized by user is NULL.
```

If I decided to check for that too, in every single API function call that takes in the Data Structure as a parameter, I'd have to include that check. Is it bad practice? Totally unnecessary? What is the general consensus on those kind of NULL checks? If I didn't check for `NULL` then someone could do: `remove(NULL, NULL)` and my library would crash his program.

`

Comment: try to compile and run this: `strcat(NULL, "test");`

Comment: use `assert` instead; then you can have both debug and release builds of your library.

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion and is quite context dependent. Many C standard functions do not do such checks. It's the caller's responsibility to pass in valid values. This adheres to the general minimalist philosophy of C. On the other hand there is also reasonable arguments in favour of such checks. So there really is no "right" answer.

Comment: `element_to_be_removed == NULL` makes no sense.

Comment: It's a broad question indeed, yet @kaylum has a nice comment, which could turn out to be an answer with an addition of sources on C related statements.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala When an `assert` is `false` though, doesn't the program exit runtime? That may not be good because that's essentially just a more graceful crash. You might want to report a warning or error but continue the program's runtime?

Comment: I'm all in favor of the assert method. There is no need to add a bunch of branches to deal with users passing wrong values. That's just not efficient. Instead put a comment on top of the function which states what values are accepted and whatnot.

Comment: @Hatefiend `assert()` is for DEBUG builds, and crashing right away (-> see *fail fast*) is IMHO the best thing a DEBUG library can do when it's used outside its contract. Passing `null` where a valid pointer is needed is violating the contract oft the library.

Comment: @melpomene why not? consider a `destroy_tree` function using `do (otherthings();) while (remove(ptr));`

Comment: @KeineLust because it's an `int`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen ooops :)

Comment: Why concentrate on NULL?  What about all the other illegal/incorrect values that may be passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, there are many approaches to this question. I'll explain one that is in wide use, together with its benefits.

What to do, in example/pseudo code

```
void remove(struct myDataStruct *s, void* element_to_be_removed)
{
    // pre-conditions:
    assert(s != NULL);
    assert(element_to_be_removed != NULL);
    assert(!isEmpty(s));

    // implementation:
    [...]

    // optional post-conditions
    // assert(s != NULL); <- maybe something more sensible
}
```

Now, what's the advantage of this method:

- Efficiency. In a release build, all these `assert()`s will just vanish. In a debug build, they will check the contract of the method is followed and immediately stop otherwise, thus helping the user of your library to locate where he went wrong.
- Readability. You clearly separate the contract-checking from your business logic. Checking of preconditions happens in the first few lines of your method, which consist only in `assert()`s.

Of course, this only applies to functions where passing e.g. `NULL` for a parameter is considered a bug in the calling code. Most of the time, this is indeed the case. The don't even try to emit a meaningful error and somehow resume, instead, **fail fast**. A bug is a bug and there's no point in continuing the program, this would only complicate debugging.

If passing `NULL` is unexpected, but not really a bug, you should go for the "logging" approach instead. This is not the case in your example.

Comment: To add to this answer, you can even do `assert(x == y && "Make sure x and y are the same number!")` and it will print out the error message as well. Win win!

Answer (score 3):

I guess depending on who the API clients will be. Where I work, usually we just do with `assert(whatever!=NULL);` at the top of the function, and have a release and a debug build.

But I guess you could do another thing, like instead of returning a `void` you could return an `int` which contains the output code. For example, if there's an error return a negative number and if it was successful return a `0`. There's a lot of C APIs which do it like this.

In my opinion, if you don't need an ultra-minimalist application, and you are not sure if the API callers will call the methods with the correct parameters, you could add it as an extra check. Otherwise, expect long nights of debugging for the API clients if they don't fully check that parameters passed are OK.

Comment: The `assert.h` calls won't really explain what went wrong right? They just simply say that assertion `...` failed on line `_` if I'm not mistaken? Is that more or less useful then providing an error such as: `Cannot perform operation because provided MyDataStructure was NULL` (note that I cannot provide line numbers in my print)

Comment: @Hatefiend yes, you are right. And usually asserts are deactivated in the release build, so you would only get them on debug. The thing though, is that while developing (usually on debug), the clients would see that their implementation is failing because of `MyDataStructure` being `NULL`. When the product is on the market though, if it fails, no one would see that it's failing because of that error. And again, usefulness depends on the situation. If you don't need a minimalist ammount of code, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very opinion based:

## No you don't.

When you call a function you **must** verify if there has a error. It's at this time that you check your data. For example:

```
int i;
int ret = scanf("%d", &i);
if (ret != 1) {
  return ERROR;
}
// here `i` is valid
```

If you check the validity of your data more than one time, this is useless. To do this, API should not check if a pointer is NULL because the user should have done it when it was needed.

```
int main(void) {
  int *api_data = malloc(sizeof *api_data);
  if (api_data == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  int ret = init_api_data(api_data); // api_data is valid
  if (ret == ERROR) {
    free(api_data);
    return 1;
  }
  free(api_data);
}

int init_api_data(int *api_data) {
  if (api_data == NULL) { // This is useless api_data has already been checked
    return ERROR;
  }
  return OK;
}
```

This is the philosophies of C, **trust the user**. Of course, this lead to bugs, that's why we try to make a better language (rust, haskell for example).

Comment: I think it's a near-pointless waste of cycles.  NULL is usually only one element in a huge set of illegal values that might be passed in:(